# Print from zebra printer using iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, printing

I am working on print functionality using zebra link-os sdk. I have little confusion about that sdk.I have zebra gK420d printer model.it not have MFI feature.is it possible print through usb or Ethernet using iPad.this sdk using external accessory framework.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Zebra SDK does support network communication.  If your GK420 and your iPad are on mutually-visible networks, then yes, you can use the SDK to print.  Take a look at the TcpConnection class and the demos with with SDK.

On a side note - Zebra offers two SDKs for their printers.  The Link-OS SDKs are meant for their Link-OS capable printers, which currently (to my knowledge) does not include the GK420.  While the Link-OS sdk should work for most of the functionality, you might want to look into their legacy sdk.

[Legacy SDK](http://www.zebra.com/us/en/products-services/software/zebralink/zebralink-multiplatform-sdk.html)

[Link-OS SDK](http://www.zebra.com/us/en/products-services/software/link-os/link-os-sdk.html)

Comment: when i goes to download both its filename look same name sdk